Jinja Escape Rendering if Conditional is Met
Within my Jinja2 template, I have the following snippet of code:
{%- if apple == "Green" %}
  {%- raw %}
    {%- for i in fruits %}
      I like to eat {{ i.fruits }}
    {%- endfor %}
  {%- endraw %}
{%- else %}
  {%- for i in fruits %}
    I like to eat {{ i.fruits }}
  {%- endfor %}
{%- endif %}

Is there a more efficient way to escape jinja logic from rendering when the above condition is met?
The problem here is that if the line "I like to eat {{ i.fruits }}" needs to be updated, it would need to be done twice.
I would prefer a more optimized approach instead of repeating lines of code.
